# Reveal background image on mouse move over front image

Tags: html, html5-canvas, fabricjs

I want to reveal the background image on mouse move on the front image. I have tried it using fabricjs but it seems the pattern image offset is updated on mouse up.

I have also tried it using the making the pixels transparent of image on mouse move but there are performance issue on slow devices. Can you suggest any better solution.

**HTML**

```
<canvas id="container"></canvas>
```

**JS**

```
var canvasWidth = window.innerWidth;
var canvasHeight = window.innerHeight;

var backgroundUrl = "http://www.keenthemes.com/preview/metronic/theme/assets/global/plugins/jcrop/demos/demo_files/image2.jpg";
var frontUrl = "http://tofurious.wpengine.netdna-cdn.com/images/textures/texture-8.jpg";

var canvas = new fabric.Canvas('container', {
    width:canvasWidth,
    height:canvasHeight,
    isDrawingMode: true 
});

fnDrawImage(backgroundUrl); 
drawPattern()

function fnDrawImage(_url){
    var Image = fabric.Image.fromURL(_url, function(oImg) { 
        oImg.width = canvasWidth;
        oImg.height = canvasHeight;
        oImg.selectable = false;
        canvas.add(oImg);   
    });     
}

function drawPattern(){
    var img = new Image();
    img.src = frontUrl;
    img.onload = function(){
        img.width = canvasWidth;
        img.height = canvasHeight;
        fnTexturePattern(img);
        //fnStartFreeDrawing(img);
    }
}

function fnTexturePattern(_img){
    var texturePatternBrush = new fabric.PatternBrush(canvas);  
    texturePatternBrush.source = _img;      
    canvas.freeDrawingBrush = texturePatternBrush;
    canvas.freeDrawingBrush.width = 30;
}
```

JSFiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/3qp5y9jb/

Comment: There is no link. And at least an actual example as what you tried and didn't work for you will be helpful

Comment: [JsFiddle Link](http://jsfiddle.net/3qp5y9jb/)